# I need to write google authentication to environment variables

Tags: python, google-drive-api

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
filename = settings.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PATH
store = file.Storage(filename)
creds = store.get()

if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_PATH, SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Now the company has a need to write the contents of the client_secret_2.json and credentials.json files to the environment variables, but I only know the path to the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the google drive API, but to set environment variables in Python you need to do the following:

```
import os

os.environ["key"] = "value"
```

So I assume you need to set the key/value pairs within `client_secret_2.json` and `credentials.json` as environment variables?